# running the powershell script without parameters should display the helpList function

Tags: powershell

Run powershell Script without parameter from commnadline argumnet then should call default custom function HelpList()

```
function HelpList() 
{  
   Write-Host "Calling HelpList function"   
} #end Help  

function clean()
{
    Write-Host "Cleaning solution"
}
```

Calling from Command line

`DepolymentScript.ps1 HelpList`
  Calling HelpList Function

DepolymentScript.ps1 Clean
    cleaning solution

DepolymentScript.ps1

then getting blank. Here I need to display  Calling HelpList Function

Comment: Could you please re-phrase your question

Comment: so is not a code writing service

Comment: Here if i call like  C:\WorkSpace\DEV\deploymentScript.ps1; HelpList  then getting "DevelopmentBuild.ps1 command line examples." But if I not pass HelpList even I need a "DevelopmentBuild.ps1 command line examples" in response

Comment: You want to execute DevelopmentBuild.ps1 in DeploymentScript.ps1 is that right ?

Comment: I want to execute script without pass parameter. But my script should able to call default function

Comment: I've added 2 approaches, hope that's clarified it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways to accomplish this. This way is a bit old school but it works:

```
param(
    $scriptParameter1 = '',
    $scriptParameter2 = ''
)

function HelpList{
    Write-Host "DevelopmentBuild.ps1 command line examples:"
}
if($scriptParameter1 -eq '' -OR $scriptParameter2 -eq ''){
    HelpList
}
```

Reading your comments I think you may want something different than what I thought. This may be more to your liking:

```
param(
    $scriptParameter1 = ''
)

function HelpList{
    Write-Host "DevelopmentBuild.ps1 command line examples:"
}
function Clean{
    #Do whatever clean does
}
switch $scriptParameter1{
    Clean {Clean}
    default {HelpList}
}
```

Comment: That is what happens in the second example. If you call the script with a Clean parameter then the clean function runs. If you call it with nothing then HelpList runs

Comment: Appreciate of your response. Perfect. Switch block works for me. Thank you so much

Comment: Thank you @@EBGreen

Answer (score 1):

Calling functions can get quiet tricky

**Question:**
Calling deploymentScript.ps1 with or without HelpList() should Display: **"Calling HelpList function**"

Calling deploymentScript.ps1 with Clean() should Display: **"Cleaning solution**

```
    function HelpList() 
{  
   Write-Host "Calling HelpList function"   
} #end Help  

function clean()
{
    Write-Host "Cleaning solution"
}
```

DepolymentScript.ps1 HelpList // Not sure how this would result in Calling HelpList Function from the console

=================================================================
SOLUTION:

**Approach 1: TESTED AND RUN**

Alternate approach that you could use is to keep the .PS as it is 
and the below arguments to the command line

`. C:\PowerShell_Scripts\deployment_script.ps1`

`dir function:\*`

Now you will be able to directly call functions by just their names

**Approach 2: TESTED and RUN**

```
 param(
    $param1 = ''
)

function HelpList{
    Write-Host "DevelopmentBuild.ps1 command line examples1:"
}
function Clean{
     Write-Host "Cleaning Solution"
}
if($param1 -eq '' -OR $param1 -eq 'HelpList')
{
    HelpList
}
if($param1 -eq 'Clean'){
    Clean
}
```

=======================================================================
[image]

Comment: I can't Vote because I don't have minimum reputation here. Sorry .That's a reason I written Thank you comments

Comment: Clint, How to call function with parameter? For Ex, UpdateVersion($VersionNumber) From command line UpdateVersion  1.1.1.1. But VersionNumber is getting blank

Comment: Thank you @@Clint